# Getting values of particular key in a nested object structure in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, string, nested, key-value

I have a n-level nested object where I have to get all the unique values for the key 'field'. Is there a way to get all the unique values for keytype 'field' in TypeScript.

output = ['TierLevel', 'CompanyType', 'CompanyService', 'City', 'StateProvince', 'Country']

```
ruleset = {
            condition: 'and',
            rules: [
                {
                    field: 'TierLevel',
                    operator: 'Equals',
                    value: '1'
                },
                {
                    field: 'CompanyType',
                    operator: 'Equals',
                    value: '7'
                },
                {
                    field: 'CompanyService',
                    operator: 'Equals',
                    value: '23'
                },
                {
                    condition: 'or',
                    rules: [
                        {
                            field: 'City',
                            operator: 'Contains',
                            value: 'york'
                        },
                        {
                            field: 'City',
                            operator: 'Contains',
                            value: 'cal'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    condition: 'or',
                    rules: [
                        {
                            field: 'StateProvince',
                            operator: 'Equals',
                            value: '3171'
                        },
                        {
                            field: 'StateProvince',
                            operator: 'Equals',
                            value: '475'
                        },
                        {
                            condition: 'or',
                            rules: [
                                {
                                    field: 'Country',
                                    operator: 'Equals',
                                    value: '224'
                                },
                                {
                                    field: 'Country',
                                    operator: 'Equals',
                                    value: '1'
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

```
    public selectedFieldsList: string[] = [];

    public getSelectedFields(ruleset: any) {
        return ruleset.rules?.map((rule: any) => {
            if (rule.rules) {
                return `( ${this.getSelectedFields(rule)} )`;
            }
            this.selectedFieldsList.push(rule.field);

            return this.selectedFieldsList;
        });
    }
```

I tried the above code. It gives the required output but it is not strongly Typed(because of the usage of 'any'). Is there any other approach where I can get the required values.

Answer (score 0):

First, start off by defining an interface for your your ruleset

```
interface Rule {
    field: string;
    operator: string;
    value: string;
}

interface RuleSet {
    condition: string;
    rules: (Rule | RuleSet)[]
}
```

Then, you'll want to write a typeguard to determine when it is a `Rule` (or a `RuleSet`):

```
const isRule = (data: Rule | RuleSet): data is Rule => {
    return 'field' in data;
}
```

Then you can use the following function:

```
const getSelectedFields = (ruleset: RuleSet): string[] => {
    const fields = ruleset.rules.flatMap((ruleOrSet: (Rule | RuleSet)) => {
        if (isRule(ruleOrSet)) {
            return ruleOrSet.field;
        }
        else {
            return getSelectedFields(ruleOrSet);
        }
    });
    return [...new Set(fields)];
}
```

In this function, you create a variable `fields` that is assigned the result of calling the `flatMap` method on the `rules` property of the `ruleset` argument. The `flatMap` method is used to map each element of the array to a new array, which is then flattened into a single array. The callback function provided to `flatMap` takes an argument named `ruleOrSet` that can be either a `Rule` or a `RuleSet`.

If `isRule` returns true, then we return the `field` property of the `Rule` object. If not, then we recursively call the `getSelectedFields` function and pass the `ruleOrSet` variable as `RuleSet`.

Lastly, we create a new `Set` variable and pass the `fields` variable as a parameter to filter all the duplicate values out of the array.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: This returns the required string[] and works as expected. Thanks a lot